# tinyMCE - source code editing in a textarea

Tags: tinymce

I'm playing around with MCE, I was wondering if there was the possibility of letting the user enter source code into a post, much like the 101010 button in this form.

Answer (score 26):

You'll need to add plugins: "code" to the initialization code as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "code"
});
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/code/

Comment: This opens up a popup. Is there an option or an plugin so that I could get the code editor in the same window using a tab perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

The option exists. One of the optional buttons has 'html' written on it and can be used to go into HTML editing mode. You can see it in [this full featured example](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/) - 6 places left of the top-right corner.

Answer (score 3):

Try 'code' plugin along with tinymce.min.js

e.g.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/plugins/code/plugin.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        plugins: "code",
        toolbar: "code" });
</script>
```