# TinyMCE is removing <style> tags

Tags: css, tinymce

I'm facing a problem with TinyMCE. When I enter a style tag in the HTML editor of TinyMCE, it removes the tags when I click update.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
     .newclasss { color:#c9c9c9; } 
</style>
```

My valid elements are follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var valid_elms = "hr[class|width|size|noshade]";
valid_elms    += "span[class|align|style],";
valid_elms    += "font[face|size|color|style],";
valid_elms    += "img[href|src|name|title|onclick|align|alt|title|";
valid_elms    += "width|height|vspace|hspace],";
valid_elms    += "iframe[id|class|width|size|noshade|src|height|";
valid_elms    += "frameborder|border|marginwidth|marginheight|";
valid_elms    += "target|scrolling|allowtransparency],style";

extended_valid_elements: valid_elms
</script>
```

Can anyone help please??

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt he's not with us to do this (Last seen Jun 14 '10)

Answer (score 78):

Since style tags are not valid XHTML, TinyMCE disabled the ability to add them outside of the  tags.

You have to add style tags to the [valid children configuration](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_children)

```
valid_children : "+body[style]"
```

Edit: This solution applies to version 3.4.2

[Source](http://community.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25443)

Comment: DOESN'T work, tinymce still removes style tags (tinymce 3.5.6)

Comment: I am not clear where I need to change the setting I read the tinymce documentation and can't find it.

Comment: @VishalKhialani wherever you initiate tinymce. I recommend you read here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Installation

Comment: This also fails in TinyMCE 4.0

Comment: Works for me with 4.1.7.
Also you can try enabling `script` tags and:
`<script>// <![CDATA[`
`document.write('<style>#jiji{color: red;}</style>');`
`// ]]></script>`

Comment: Don't replace any Magento code, just install this free extension from GitHub to fix the issue. github.com/magefan/module-wysiwyg-advanced 
More info can be found here
https://magefan.com/blog/magento-2.3-tinymce-4-text-color-tool-missing

Comment: Worked for me, I am using TinyMCE 5.0

Comment: Worked for me, I am using TinyMCE 4.9.3

Comment: Worked for me, I am using TinyMCE 6.3.1.

Comment: Don't really understand the reason though. 1. My `<style>` are in `<head>` and not in `<body>`, which is correct. 2. [There's quite a lot info here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering) indicates that TinyMCE now support full HTML5.

Comment: My guess: in my case it's the removal of Full page plugin when moving from 5 to 6. This plugin provides a way to edit `<head>`.

Answer (score 7):

```
"hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style],img[href|src|name|title|onclick|align|alt|title|width|height|vspace|hspace],iframe[id|class|width|size|noshade|src|height|frameborder|border|marginwidth|marginheight|target|scrolling|allowtransparency],style[type]"
```

Let me know how that works for you

Comment: UmbracoCMS 6.1.6, valid_children didn't work, this one did. Thank you so much. No idea why style[*] wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

If you put tinyMCE in fullpage mode, you can put styles in the `<head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        plugins : "fullpage",
});
</script>
```

Comment: but than would add doctype tag

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky but I'm using TinyMCE 4 and was in a pinch, so I added a `<script>` tag in the TinyMCE editor's [Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408998/tinymce-source-code-editing-in-a-textarea) view and used [jQuery to change the styles](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
<script>$("#signup").css("font-weight", "bold");</script>
```

This assumes that TinyMCE has been setup not to disallow script tags, and your page already has jQuery included in it like mine did, if not you could use standard [javascript to change styles](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Changing_Element_Styles).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I need to do the following in `TinyMCE 4.5.7`:

```js
tinyMCE.schema.addValidChildren("body[style]")
```

Comment: this only partially worked. my style element is emitted as <style><!-- .rule { .. } --></style>