# TinyMCE remove CSS from my HTML code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm using a Javascript function to get the content of an HTML file hosted on my server, and then add the content to a TinyMCE editor.

this is the function :

```
function LoadTemplate(url) {
    $.post(url, function (data) {
        // Get the editor instance that we want to interact with.
        var ed = tinyMCE.get('html_editor');
        ;
        // Insert the response into TinyMCE editor
        ed.setContent(data, {format : 'raw'});

        // Hide The Templates Div
        HideTemplates();
    }, "text");
}
```

After the user select a file, and click Load template, the HTML file is inserted into the TinyMCE editor without any problem, but After clicking submit, I found in the database the head of the document, and the CSS in style tag removed by TinyMCE.

I added to TinyMCE General options :

```
            element_format : "html",
            verify_html : false,
```

but I still get the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default TinyMCE is only interested in your page's content which is contained within the document's `<body>` part. If you want to have TinyMCE edit every part of your document, especially the `<head>` section, then you'll need the fullpage plugin.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:fullpage

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now the editor don't remove the header and body, but still remove any CSS code in the header. is there any solution for that ?

Comment: @McShark  Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037501/tinymce-is-removing-style-tags