# TinyMCE 3.4.7 stop stripping code

Tags: php, html, joomla, tinymce

TinyMCE 3.4.7 DOES NOT have code cleanup options... how can I stop it stripping all my tags out?

```
<?php
    $editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
    echo $editor->display('description', $this->lotdata->description, '550', '400', '60', '20', false);
?>
```

I have added some tags to the whitelist in the options but it still cleans everything out when loading the text (I have added tags directly to the database entry and they get stripped off if I load it in the editor).

Comment: If this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758660/when-i-save-span-with-style-to-mysql-style-is-deleted/9758950#9758950

Comment: Wrong language, but I'll see if there is an equivalent.

Comment: Adding a params array to getEditor isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was adding `JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW` to `JRequest::getVar`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if Joomla's text filtering is getting in the way here. It was the only way I could get Tiny to stop stripping my code.
On 1.6/1.7:

1. Go to Article Manager
2. Options
3. Text Filtering
4. Select the Super Users group
5. Select No Filtering
6. Save

On 2.5 the location changed to the Text Filtering option in the Global Configuration section