# Django-TinyMCE: How to configure it properly?

Tags: django, django-forms, tinymce

I'm fiddling around with [django-tinyMCE](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce) and noticed that some of the configurations are not getting applied. Here is the code from my settings.py

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme' : 'advanced',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1' : 'bold,italic,underline,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,link,unlink',
    'theme_advanced_buttons2' : '',
    'theme_advanced_buttons3' : '',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' : 'top',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align': 'left',
    'paste_text_sticky': 'true',
    'paste_text_sticky_default' : 'true',
    'valid_styles' : 'font-weight,font-style,text-decoration',
}
```

The ones which aren't working are:
paste_text_sticky, paste_text_sticky_default and valid_styles.

What I'm basically trying to do is:

Only allow

- the text to be "bold/italic/underlined"
- lists (bullets, numbers)
- links

Everything else is forbidden.

Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use Python True/False for `paste_text_sticky` and `paste_text_sticky_default`.

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme' : 'advanced',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1' : 'bold,italic,underline,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,link,unlink',
    'theme_advanced_buttons2' : '',
    'theme_advanced_buttons3' : '',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' : 'top',
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align': 'left',
    'paste_text_sticky': True,
    'paste_text_sticky_default' : True,
    'valid_styles' : 'font-weight,font-style,text-decoration',
}
```

Take a look at this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037501/tinymce-is-removing-style-tags) related to valid children and styles. Hope that helps you out.